# How to get mob heads effectively?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As of 1.8, [mob heads](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_head) of a mob will drop if the respective mob is killed by a charged creeper's explosion.

This is really hard, as (1) finding a charged creeper is rare and (2) luring it near mobs is also difficult and very error prone.

What is the most effective way to get mob heads?

Comment: I assume spawning them in is out?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Well, I'm playing in Survival, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Minecraft 1.13 we have [Tridents](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trident). They can be enchanted with the Channeling enchantment that creates a lightning bolt during a thunderstorm if it hits a mob.

Using it thus gives one a very easy to use way to get mob heads since finding charged creepers is no longer a concern.

Answer (score 5):

I found a tutorial on the minecraft wiki that seems to be the best way to farm them. It will still take a long time, and it will probably be really hard to build and maintain but if you REALLY want the heads this is probably the most efficient way.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Charged_creeper_farming